# Laptop Volume Up key is decreasing key sets volume back to 100% from overamplified value

Tags: sound, keyboard, volume-control

I used Windows for a long and yesterday I switched to Linux, Ubuntu 20.04. Sound is much lower here than Windows. But if I go to `Settings` -> `Sound` -> `Output` volume to max (more than 100%) it plays as loud as that was on Windows. But the problem is when I press volume up button it changes back to 100%. (May be volume up button detection software considers 100% as max). How can I fix this and make volume up key able to increase the sound until it reaches max?

Comment: Have you set the `Over-Amplification` flag to on in `System Volume`? I have that flag set and if I set the volume to 100% pressing the media `volume up` key increases the volume in steps to beyond the 100% marker.

Comment: Under `Settings` -> `Sound` I found Over-Amplification checkbox. Is that the thing you telling to be turned on? It's already turned on and still not working. If that's not the the thing you are telling can you help please? (Edit: also I can raise the sound beyond 100% marker by dragging the slider in the settings dialog box. But I cannot do that by using keyboard `volume up` key)

Comment: Yes, the over-amp setting to on. If you set the sound slider to 100% then press the `volume up` media key, it should increase the sound beyond the 100% position in steps.

Comment: No it doesn't work on my system. If it's more than 100% pressing `volume up` sets the volume back to 100%